# iis7 / asp.net not showing modification of a file

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have currently moved my asp.net 4.0 web application onto IIS7 (windows 2008 server). I used a test folder to hold files from a directory on the localhost machine, however; when I moved the aspx file over and changed the code(on the server), the application keeps throwing this error

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\***\Desktop\TestFolder\'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\****\Desktop\TestFolder\'.
```

I only have two functions that deal with directories and neither function points to that test directory anymore.

```
private int checkForFileNumbers()
{
    string url = "c:/***/realfolder";
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(url);
    return directory.GetFiles().Length;
}

private void checkForFiles()
{
    string url = "c:/***/realfolder";
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(url);
    foreach (FileInfo files in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        FileDropDownList.Items.Add(files.Name);
    }
}
```

I have tried commenting everything in this aspx file out, only to find that this problem still occurs. I performed the issrestart from the cmd line and nothing changed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is an exception, the error message will also include a stack trace that will point you to the location in your code where this error is occurring. Follow the stack trace.

Comment: the stack trace keeps point to these two functions and the part of the code that calls them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a deployment problem. Your error message is clearly out of sync with your current code. The actual code that is being run from IIS must be coming from an out-of-date binary. As a starting point, I would delete all DLLs in your bin directory on the server and redeploy fresh DLLs. The may also require you to refresh your aspx files depending on what kind of project type you're using.

Once you get this sorted out, I would take another look at how you are deploying updates to your site. Visual Studio and IIS 7 offer some neat deployment options if you want to go that way. Also, you could deploy via Git or SVN. But deployment by manual replacing single files is going to lead you to the type of trouble you are currently experiencing.

Comment: It appears that the Deleting my DLLs and copying over the most current did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If `realFolder` directory exists under root of your web-app or itself is root then use `Server.MapPath` method to get real path of virtual folder.

For instance,

```
String rootPath=Server.MapPath("~"); // It will return real path of current web-app's root.
//OR - In case if want use Server property from separate code  file.
String rootPath=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/testFolder");
```

Comment: what would be the problem with using the code that I've previously written. Just curious.

Comment: @MasterP - I've guess from that error description. Path is not resolved/found.

Comment: I tried using the Server.MapPath function, however; that didn't fix the problem

Comment: If I completely removed the file it will say "file not found", however; if I put the file back in the directory(regardless of what code is present on the aspx file) it will throw that same error.

Comment: @MasterP - Read my post again - If "realFolder" exists under the root of web app then you have to use Server.MapPath() method. If your are point other local directory then be careful to write a path. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not referencing the path in your code, it's probably either in one of your config files, HttpModules, Global.asax, or perhaps a DLL.

What other components are you using?

Before moving it to a server, have you tried running the site under IIS on your local machine? Maybe attach a debugger and see where the error is thrown?

Oh, FWIW, the IIS AppPool identity will need to have read permission for your `C:/***/whatever` folder.

Comment: When you're running in VS, the app uses your user permissions. When you move the app to IIS, the app uses the permissions of the identity assigned to its AppPool.