# ASP.NET 2.0 webforms pages not updating properly after adding JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis-7

I have an asp.net (2.x) application running on IIS 7.  We have just recently started incorporating JQuery into these pages and it's going pretty well.

However, when we post the pages to the server they're not updating properly.  The physical files are definitely updating, however, when the site is loaded the IIS server appears to be loading the old files.  For some reason they seem to be caching, they've never done this before.  The site is several years old.

We don't have IIS caching enabled and it's not happening on the browser (it's the .cs files that are not updating properly).  Any idea what could be causing this?  I can't stop IIS every time I post a page change.

Answer (score 0):

You could be publishing the site to IIS and IIS believes your old web app and the revised web app are two different applications. Then, when you try to request that page from IIS, you're served the old version because it still exists.

Have you tried going into IIS manager and looking through the web applications configured through IIS? I suspect you have two versions of the same web app but are under the impression that there is only 1.

Comment: I just checked to be sure but there is only the one app.  We actually didn't set up a new application, we've just been adding pages/modifying existing ones.

Comment: Is this problem only related to pages that have JQuery? Have you been able to see any of your modifications or new pages?

Comment: I've only seen it on our new pages and the only real difference on these pages is the addition of jquery.  I recycled IIS yesterday during the work day and it seems like that refreshed the pages but it wasn't instantaneous, it took a little while.  But once that happened I was able to see changes.  Still not sure why this lag?

Comment: Ah ok. Than read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767831/iis7-asp-net-not-showing-modification-of-a-file